# I'm trying to understand reduce and i'm scratching my head about this, why is this code not giving the expected result

Tags: arrays, loops, logic, reduce

I am reduce an array of object into a single object that should look like this :

`

```
result = {
  23 : [{obj of kyle}, {obj of jade}],
  29 : [{obj of ruby}]
  32 : [{obj of mat}]
}
```

`

I have used reduce to do this, each person variable will refer to an object of the array to reduce, and they all collapse into a single object refered to with the variable group, the initial value of that object is an empty object {}, so with an if statement i checked first if it's empty, then create a key named age with a new empty array as value and push the person object into that empty array, and if the key age exists, then skip the new array creation and push that corresponding person object into the corresponding array.

what's wrong with this code?

`

```
const people = [
  {name: "kyle", age: 23},
  {name: "jade", age: 23},
  {name: "ruby", age: 29},
  {name: "mat", age: 32}
]

let result = people.reduce(function(person, group){
  
  const age = person.age;
  if(group[age]==null){
    group[age] = []
}
    group[age].push(person);
  
  
  return group
},{})


console.log(result);
```

`

not what i expected

Answer (score 0):

Looking again at your code it seems that you can fix your own code by replacing `person` and `group` in your callback function inside `reduce` like so

```js
const people = [
  {name: "kyle", age: 23},
  {name: "jade", age: 23},
  {name: "ruby", age: 29},
  {name: "mat", age: 32}
]

let result = people.reduce(function(group, person){
  
  const age = person.age;
  if(group[age]==null){
       group[age] = []
    }
    group[age].push(person);
    return group
},{})


console.log(result);
```

You can do something like this as well

```js
const people = [
  {name: "kyle", age: 23},
  {name: "jade", age: 23},
  {name: "ruby", age: 29},
  {name: "mat", age: 32}
];


const result = people.reduce((acc, curr) => {
      if (!acc[curr.age]) {
          return {...acc, [curr.age]: [curr]}
      }
      return {...acc, [curr.age]: [...acc[curr.age], curr]};
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

What we did here is initiating it with a new object like you did, then for each element in the array denoted as `curr` for current we check if our new object (denoted as `acc` for accumulator) has a key with this age already of `curr.age`. If not we make an array for this age and put the current element inside.
Else, if this age key already exist just add to that age array the current element.

Comment: thank you for your answer, it's clearer now!

Comment: @RayElshobokshy Glad to help, you were close on your own, just needed a little tweak.